# Create a functional field in OpenERP via Web-UI

Tags: odoo

```
Is there any other method similar to using the following aspects in Web-interface:
- function field
- related field
- constraint
```

I got info regarding `function field that we can use js` but I dont know how its used. If you know the information, share it.

```
Thanks & Regards,
Atchuthan
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do this as you need to write the python code for the function.  OpenERP doesn't support this kind of behaviour by design. The idea is it has a very powerful inheritance system for writing your own modules.

Ditto with constraints. Regular constraints are defined in code, SQL constraints are also defined in code and processed when the model is registered.